# Distriqt Google Analytics Extension fails in Air Debug Launcher (ADL)

Tags: google-analytics, air, air-native-extension, ane, distriqt

Exception fault: VerifyError: Error #1014: Class com.distriqt.extension.googleanalytics::Tracker could not be found.

The issue does NOT occur when installed to a device.

The extension has been added to the application descriptor.

I have other Distriqt extensions (notifications, dialog) already in my app which are working fine.

Setup: Mac / FDT / AIR SDK 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We accidentally missed a few classes in default library of the first release of this ANE.

Grab the update and it should resolve this issue.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for that, but with the update I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Update: Exiting before the getTracker() call if GoogleAnalytics.isSupported returns false, prevents app from crash so the update did fix. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to copy and rename your ANE: *ane-file-name*.ane to *ane-file-name*.swc, and also add it to your project (you must have both ane and swc)